# Is the comma necessary in this situation?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I was going through two questions on an ACT Practice test and was wondering about the choice of punctuation.

Problem 1:

To add to the confusion, every New Year's Day **a person according** to this Korean counting system, becomes a year older, regardless of his or her actual birthday.

According to the test, there should be a comma between person and according. Can anyone explain why?

Problem 2: Other letters are **solemn; speaking** of relatives and friends who had died.

According to the test, the semi-colon should be replaced with a comma. However, I thought that there are two independent clauses, so there should be a semi-colon or period. Please explain why there is a comma.

Thanks!

Comment: The answers are pretty straightforward if you review examples on restrictive and nonrestrictive clauses.

Comment: So in the first example is the information non-essential making it a nonrestrictive clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma sets off nonessential information. The phrase *according to this Korean counting system* may be removed without altering meaning or clarity. The same applies to your second example - which means the comma, rather than the semicolon, should be used.